# What is the cleanest/easiest way to read in a config file

Tags: linux, bash, configuration-files, init

I want to create a config file with key=value pairs in groupings so that I can iterate through the config file in groups of key=value pairs.

Example config file:

```
#group1
var1=test1
var2=test2
var3=test3

#group2
var1=text4
var2=text5
var3=test6
var4=test7

#group3
var3=test8
```

Is there a simple way to parse a config file similar to this layout where each group may include/exclude parameters, and each iteration of the parsing loop will pull in that specific groups key=value pairs?

Does bash have a built in config parser? This is for an openrc init script.

Comment: This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410306/bash-read-in-config-file-with-multiple-instances-of-the-same-variable?rq=1 You just need to start processing lines when you see the section header, and stop when you get to the next header.

Comment: @randy, you have duplicate keys in your groupings. Is that intended or was it just an example.For ex can group1 and group2 have separate variables ?

Comment: If you have control over the config file format, rather than dealing with a file you must parse, it is far easier to write the config out in a format you can `source`. You have even greater flexibility with the introduction of **associative arrays**. E.g. (`declare -A group1; group1=( [var1]="test 1" [var2]="test 2" ... )` ). Then rather than parsing it, just `. /path/to/my/config` and then simply use `${group1[var2]}`, etc..

Comment: When you put the config for each group in another config file, you can source the file you want to have active.

Comment: When you call settings for group2 first and group1 afterwards, do you want to have var4 unset/empty or can it still have the value test7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the answers in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207585/dd-style-parameters-to-a-bash-script), you could do something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [ -f "${HOME}/.${0##*/}" ]; then
    config="${HOME}/.${0##*/}rc"
else
    config="/etc/${0##*/}"
fi

if [ -f "$config" ]; then
    section=global
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ ^(#|$) ]]; then continue; fi
        if [[ $line =~ ^\[[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\]$ ]]; then
            section=${line#[}
            section=${section%]}
        elif [[ $line =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*= ]]; then
            eval "${section}_${line%%=*}"=\${line#*=}
        fi
    done <"$config"
fi
```

This assumes `bash`, and parses config files like this:

```
# comment

global1=gval1
global2=gval2

[section1]
variable_1=value_11
variable_2=value_12

[section2]
variable_1=value_21
variable_2=value_22
```

It sets the variables named in the config file, with the name prefixed by the name of the section.  Comments and blank lines are ignored.

Proof of concept:

```
set | egrep '^(global|section)[^=]' | \
while read -r line; do
    key=${line%%=*}   
    eval "val=\${$key}"
    printf '%s = [%s]\n' "$key" "$val"
done
```

Output:

```
global_global1 = [gval1]
global_global2 = [gval2]
section1_variable_1 = [value_11]
section1_variable_2 = [value_12]
section2_variable_1 = [value_21]
section2_variable_2 = [value_22]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `cut` using the equals sign `=` as a delimiter

If `$line` is every valid line, (you can escape lines starting with comments and empty lines)

```
key=`cut -f1 -d '=" $line` 
value=`cut -f2 -d '=" $line`
```

Comment: This doesn't apply grouping as in his example. What if he wants `var1` from group2 instead of group3? If it were as simple as your answer, he could just source the file instead.

Comment: @jordanm, good point. I have asked the author to provide some content

Comment: Also, this is far less efficient than simply using `read`: `IFS='=' read key value <<< "$line"`.